# cy.readFile is throwing AssertionError in e2e before() block in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to put a check before every test that checks whether a file exists or not, under fixtures dir.

Here's the `e2e.js` file I tried:

```javascript
require('./commands');

before(() => {

    const filePath = 'cypress/fixtures/mydata.json';

    cy.readFile(filePath, { log: false }).then((data) => {
        if (data !== null) {
            cy.log(`File '${filePath}' exists.`);
        } else {
            cy.log(`File '${filePath}' does not exist.`);
        }
    });

});
```

I tried multiple different ways around like the code above but it doesn't work. The execution doesn't go inside the else block, rather, throws an assertion error and stops execution altogether.

I tried also using `fs.existsSync()` and `cy.fixture()` but fs is not allowed to be used in a cypress test file and got the same result with fixture(). How can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plain javascript try/catch to handle checking for the data

```js
let data;
try {
  require('./cypress/fixture/data.json')
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e)   // the message is sent to the dev console
  data = null
}

before(() => {
  if (data !== null) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: you have just given me a great perspective on how to separate js code and cypress code! so simple, yet so elegant, thanks a lot!